# Crop the string only after closing tag

Tags: php

I want to cut the string, if the string length is greater than 80.My need is if the string contain tag and cut the string in between the opening and closing tag,string crop should be only after closing tag.THis is my code.

```
<?php 
    echo $word='hello good morning<span class="em emj2"></span> <span class="em emj13"></span>      <span class="em emj19"></span> <span class="em emj13"></span> hai';
    $a=strlen($word);    
    if($a>80)
     {
      echo substr($word,0,80);
     }
    else
        echo $word;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that my answer is not in good ethics as according to stackoverflow, as I dont have time to explain exactly how every part of it works. But this is a function I use to crop strings and maintain the HTML code.

```
function truncate($text, $length, $suffix = '&hellip;', $isHTML = true) {
    $i = 0;
    $simpleTags=array('br'=>true,'hr'=>true,'input'=>true,'image'=>true,'link'=>true,'meta'=>true);
    $tags = array();
    if($isHTML){
        preg_match_all('/<[^>]+>([^<]*)/', $text, $m, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE | PREG_SET_ORDER);
        foreach($m as $o){
            if($o[0][1] - $i >= $length)
                break;
            $t = substr(strtok($o[0][0], " \t\n\r\0\x0B>"), 1);
            if($t[0] != '/' && (!isset($simpleTags[$t])))
                $tags[] = $t;
            elseif(end($tags) == substr($t, 1))
                array_pop($tags);
            $i += $o[1][1] - $o[0][1];
        }
    }
    $output = substr($text, 0, $length = min(strlen($text),  $length + $i));
    $output2 = (count($tags = array_reverse($tags)) ? '</' . implode('></', $tags) . '>' : '');
    $pos = (int)end(end(preg_split('/<.*>| /', $output, -1, PREG_SPLIT_OFFSET_CAPTURE)));
    $output.=$output2;
    $one = substr($output, 0, $pos);
    $two = substr($output, $pos, (strlen($output) - $pos));
    preg_match_all('/<(.*?)>/s', $two, $tags);
    if (strlen($text) > $length) { $one .= $suffix; }
    $output = $one . implode($tags[0]);
    $output = str_replace('</!-->','',$output); 
    return $output;
}
```

Then simply do like so:

```
truncate($your_string, '80', $suffix = '&hellip;', $isHTML = true);
```

Comment: Your code will remove the html tags.I want to complete the html code within the specified length.